# Usar a classe para adicionar o próprio objeto em um vector que fica em outro objeto

Tags: python-3.x, c++, classes, objetos

Em python fiz o seguinte código:

```
class Escola:
    def __init__( self, escola_nome ):
        self.escola_nome = escola_nome
        self.alunos = []
    
    
class Aluno:
    def __init__( self, nome ):
        self.nome = nome
        self.escola = None
    
    def matricular( self, escola ):
        if not self.escola:
            escola.alunos.append( self )
            self.escola = escola
            print( f'{self.nome} se matriculou na escola {self.escola.escola_nome}' )
        
        else:
            print( f'{self.nome} já está matriculado na escola {self.escola.escola_nome}' )


estadual = Escola( "Alguma escola aqui" )

alguem = Aluno( "lucas" )
alguem.matricular( estadual )

print( f"Escola de Lucas: {alguem.escola.escola_nome}" )
```

No código acima o método "matricular" adiciona o objeto que está sendo usado numa lista que fica em outra classe.

tentei fazer esse mesmo exercício em C++, estou com dificuldade de fazer a classe adicionar o próprio objeto em um vector que fica na outra classe e também estou com alguns outros problemas.

O código ficou assim:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <vector> // std::vector


struct Escola
{
    Escola( std::string school_name="" ): nome_escola( school_name ) {}
    
    std :: string nome_escola;
    std :: vector< Aluno > estudantes; // Erro: o struct "Aluno" não existe
};


struct Aluno
{
    Aluno( std::string name ): nome( name ) {}
    void matricular( Escola& school );
    // se colocasse o struct "Aluno" antes do struct "Escola" também haveria erro
    // pois o struct "Escola" ainda não estaria definido seria preciso usá-lo aqui
    
    std :: string nome;
    Escola escola;
};


void Aluno :: matricular( Escola& school )
{
    //if( escola != NULL ) não sei verificar se um objeto está vazio. dessa maneira não funcionou
    school.estudantes.push_back( /*Aqui deveria ser adicionado o objeto que está usando o método "matricular". não sei como faz isso em C++*/ );
    escola = school;
}


int main( void )
{
    Escola estadual = Escola( "Algum nome de escola aqui" );
    Aluno inteligente = Aluno( "João" );
    
    inteligente.matricular( estadual );
    
    std :: cout << inteligente.escola.nome_escola << "\n";
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> tentei fazer esse mesmo exercício em C++, estou com dificuldade de fazer a classe adicionar o próprio objeto em um vector que fica na outra classe e também estou com alguns outros problemas.

Essa composição de dados parece estranha em português, ou Python ou C.
Talvez seja mais natural `matricular()` ser um método de `Escola` e não de `Aluno`. De todo modo uma referência cíclica existe.

#### Um exemplo simples

```
int main(void)
{
    Escola estadual = Escola("Alguma Escola");
    estadual.lista_os_caras("Sem alunos ainda");

    Aluno inteligente = Aluno("Joao");
    Aluno um          = Aluno("Jhonny");
    estadual.matricular(inteligente);
    estadual.matricular(um);

    estadual.lista_os_caras("Com alunos");
    return 0;
}
```

mostra

```
Sem alunos ainda
0 matriculados em "Alguma Escola"
    matricular()    Joao matriculado em "Alguma Escola"
    matricular()    Jhonny matriculado em "Alguma Escola"
Com alunos
2 matriculados em "Alguma Escola"
Joao
Jhonny
```

#### o programa todo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Aluno
{
    Aluno(std::string name) : nome(name), escola("Sem Matricula") {}
    string nome;
    string escola;
};

struct Escola
{
    Escola() : Escola(""){};
    Escola(string school_name = "") : nome_escola(school_name){};

    std ::string        nome_escola;
    std ::vector<Aluno> estudantes;

    void lista_os_caras(const char*);
    void matricular(Aluno&);
};
int main(void)
{
    Escola estadual = Escola("Alguma Escola");
    estadual.lista_os_caras("Sem alunos ainda");

    Aluno inteligente = Aluno("Joao");
    Aluno um          = Aluno("Jhonny");
    estadual.matricular(inteligente);
    estadual.matricular(um);

    estadual.lista_os_caras("Com alunos");
    return 0;
}


void Escola::lista_os_caras(const char* tit)
{
    if (tit != nullptr) cout << tit << "\n";

    cout << estudantes.size() << " matriculados em \"" << nome_escola
         << "\"\n";
    for (auto a : estudantes) cout << a.nome << "\n";
}


void Escola::matricular(Aluno& aluno)
{
    aluno.escola = nome_escola;
    estudantes.push_back(aluno);
    cout << "    matricular()    " << 
        aluno.nome << " matriculado em \"" <<
        aluno.escola << "\"\n";
}
```

Compare e talvez ajude em algo.